# Don't know where to start given the probabilities

Tags: probability

Until recently, residents of a small town choose to dine at their town's only restaurant, Beslow. However, another restaurant, Kaja, recently opened close by. Worried about his business, the owner of Beslow is concerned about the effect on his business and hence, he has been collecting info. Analysis of the info suggests the following probabilities for customers switching where they prefer to dine each week.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
& \text{From Beslow} & \text{From Kaja} \\ \hline
\text{To Beslow} & 0.75 & 0.40\\ \hline
\text{To Kaja} & 0.25 & 0.60\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

1. At the end of the 1st four weeks, what proportion of the town’s population were still dining at Beslow?
2. In the long-term, what proportion of the town’s population will do their shopping at Kaja?

My initial attempt at first part of the question yield me an answer of 0.56 but I have a feeling that this is the wrong answer.

Assuming if my answer for Part 1 does hold true, I am puzzled about where to begin for Part 2 especially when, it didn't mention the duration of "long-haul".

Comment: Hint: Do you know any linear algebra? If so it may help you to think of how to use this matrix to calculate next week if this week's percentages are $(B,K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some matrix: $\mathbf P = \begin{bmatrix}0.75 & 0.40 \\ 0.25 & 0.60\end{bmatrix}$ and initial state $\vec{s_0}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

The solution to the first question is taken from $\vec{s_4}=\mathbf P^4 \cdot\vec{s_0}$.

$$\begin{align}\vec{s_4}
& =\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac 3 4 & \tfrac 2 5 \\ \tfrac 1 4 & \tfrac 3 5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\\ & =\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac {99385} {160000} & \tfrac {96984}{160000} \\ \tfrac {60615}{160000} & \tfrac {63016}{160000}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\\ & =\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac {99385} {160000} \\ \tfrac {60615}{160000} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

---

The solution to the second is taken from the matrix $\mathbf Q= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \mathbf P^n $.  Specifically, the equilibrium state is: $\vec{s_\infty} = \mathbf Q \cdot\vec{s_0}$ .

That's what "the long haul" means; as the number of weeks increases, the system (hopefully) reaches an equilibrium state.

An easier way to obtain this is observing that *if* the system tends to equilibrium, that means $\mathbf P \mathbf Q = \mathbf Q$ so then $(\mathbf P-\mathbf I_{2})\mathbf Q =\mathbf O_{2}$ where $\mathbf I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, and $\mathbf O_{2}$ is the corresponding zero matrix.

A solution to this can be found by defining function $f(\mathbf A)$ as returning matrix $\bf A$ with the topmost row elements all replaced by $1$.  If $f(\mathbf P-\mathbf I_2)$ is invertible then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf Q & = f(\mathbf P-\mathbf I_2)^{-1}\cdot f(\mathbf O_2)
\\ & = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ \tfrac 1 4 & -\tfrac 2 5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\\ & = \begin{bmatrix}\tfrac 8{13} & \tfrac{20}{13} \\ \tfrac 5 {13} & -\tfrac {20}{13} 5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\\ & =\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac 8{13} & \tfrac 8{13} \\ \tfrac 5{13} & \tfrac 5 {13}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

You may have encountered this when learning about **Markov Chains**. (A topic on which I am apparently rusty, myself.)

Then $\vec{s_\infty} = \mathbf Q\cdot \vec{s_0} = \begin{bmatrix}\tfrac 8{13} \\ \tfrac 5{13}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Appologies, @iterence .  I am apparently rusty on this myself.  Revision time!